# Square root of dual number

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, hypercomplex-numbers

We know the ring of dual numbers over the real field $\mathbb{R}$, is defined as $\mathbb{R}[\epsilon] = \{a+b\epsilon~|~a,b\in\mathbb{R} ~\text{and}~ \epsilon^2 = 0\}.$ Is the square root of $\epsilon,~i.e.~\sqrt{\epsilon}$ defined? If yes, what is its value? If no, how to show its non-existence? To make it more general, does $\epsilon^\alpha$ for $0<|\alpha|<1$ exist?

Comment: Write down the square of $a + b \varepsilon$, in terms of $a$ and $b$. Can you choose $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$ so that it equals $0 + 1\varepsilon$?

Comment: Thank you, it cleared the doubt.

Comment: Is there a square root allowing other hypercomplex numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ exists. Then $\epsilon = (a+b\epsilon)^2$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, ~\text{with}~ a \neq 0.$ Then $a^2+2ab\epsilon = \epsilon$ which implies $a=0,$ contradiction.

Comment: More generally, $a+b\epsilon$ has a square root iff $a>0$ or $a=b=0$.

Comment: Why do you assume that the square root of $\epsilon$ is a dual number? Just as square root of -1 is not real, square root of $\epsilon$ con be outside of duals.

Comment: @Anixx, by existence I mean is square root the dual number $\epsilon$ a dual number?

Comment: Definitely, no. And I think it is problematic to define it in other way as well. But if we speak about $\epsilon^\epsilon$, it is not a dual number but can be defined by adding infinite divergent integrals to the set.